# How to automatically create a new folder of the same name to another location

Tags: macos

I'm currently using osx10.10.4.
When to create a folder named 'B' in 'a folder',  I want to know how that automatically  Create a new empty folder named 'B' in 'c folder.
ps. Rather than copying the files in the folder B
I want to create a new folder of same name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the last part of your question means exactly but here is how to create folder `B` in both `a folder` and `b folder` at the same time - even if neither exits beforehand.

```
mkdir -p "a folder/B" "b folder/B"
```